# Convert int to a vector of strings

Tags: string, vector, rust

I am trying to convert long numbers to a string vector. For example, `17562` would become `["1", "7", "5", "6", "2"]`. I have seen a lot of examples of converting ints to strings, but no ints to string vectors. I want to iterate over each digit individually.

Here is what I have so far, but it isn't working.

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let values: Vec<&str> = x.to_string().split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

Gives me the compiler error of :

```
<anon>:3:29: 3:42 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
<anon>:3     let values: Vec<&str> = x.to_string().split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();

<anon>:3:88: 6:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 3:87...
<anon>:3     let values: Vec<&str> = x.to_string().split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();
<anon>:4     println!("{:?}", values);
<anon>:5     
<anon>:6 }
<anon>:3:5: 3:88 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 3:4
<anon>:3     let values: Vec<&str> = x.to_string().split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();

<anon>:3:5: 3:88 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
<anon>:3     let values: Vec<&str> = x.to_string().split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();
```

The equivalent of what I am trying to do in python would be `x = 42; x = list(str(x)); print(x)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the first problem is that you don't store the result of `x.to_string()` anywhere.  As such, it will cease to exist at the end of the expression, meaning that `values` will be trying to reference a value that no longer exists.  Hence the error.  The simplest solution is to just store the temporary string somewhere so that it continues to exist:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let x_str = x.to_string();
    let values: Vec<&str> = x_str.split(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

Second problem: this outputs `["42"]` because you told it to split on letters.  You probably meant to use `is_numeric`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let x_str = x.to_string();
    let values: Vec<&str> = x_str.split(|c: char| c.is_numeric()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

Third problem: this outputs `["", "", ""]`, because those are the three strings *between* numeric characters.  Split's argument is the *separator*.  Thus, the third problem is that you're using entirely the wrong method to begin with.

The closest *direct* equivalent to the Python code you listed would be:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let values: Vec<String> = x.to_string().chars().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

At last, it outputs: `["4", "2"]`.

But, this is horribly inefficient: this takes the integer, allocates an intermediate buffer, prints the integer to it, turns it into a string.  It takes each code point in that string, allocates an intermediate buffer, prints the code point to it, turns it into a string.  Then it collects all these strings into a `Vec`, possibly reallocating more than once.

It *works*, but is a bit wasteful.  If you don't care about waste, you can stop reading now.

You can make things a bit less wasteful by collecting code points instead of strings:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let values: Vec<char> = x.to_string().chars().collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

This outputs: `['4', '2']`.  Note the different quotes because we're using `char` instead of `String`.

We can remove the intermediate allocations from `Vec` resizing by pre-allocating its storage, which gives us this version:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42u32; // no negatives!
    let values = {
        if x == 0 {
            vec!['0']
        } else {
            // pre-allocate Vec so there's no resizing
            let digits = 1 + (x as f64).log10() as u32;
            let mut cs = Vec::with_capacity(digits as usize);
            let mut div = 10u32.pow(digits - 1);
            while div > 0 {
                cs.push((b'0' + ((x / div) % 10) as u8) as char);
                div /= 10;
            }
            cs
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}", values);     
}
```

Unless you're doing this in a loop, I'd just stick to the correct, wasteful version.

Comment: Looks great. Thank you so much for clarifying why I need to store the string version.

Comment: Isn't this whole point of the `Iterator::size_hint` method? So that you don't have to pre calculate vector lengths yourself?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, except it's impossible for `chars` to know how many code points it's going to decode, so it can't possibly tell `Vec` how big it needs to be.

Comment: [Not so](http://is.gd/BCVmeW). It's actually trivial to know the **bounds** of the number of characters in a UTF-8 string, which is what `size_hint` allows for.

Comment: @Shepmaster [`FromIterator for Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1232-L1233) only uses the lower bound, [`Chars`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/str/mod.rs#L407) provides both.  In this case, the lower bound will be roughly one quarter of the actual number, which `Vec` will round up to (in the case of 42) 2, which means it will have to resize at *least* once.  I still consider my code more correct if you're trying to minimise reallocations.  :)

Comment: Hmm. I guess it has to pick either the min or the max, although I'm surprised that the max is completely ignored. I would have expected something along the lines of `max.unwrap_or(min + 1)`, as avoiding reallocation seems to save more.

Comment: Also, your last example returns items in reverse order; was that intentional?

Comment: @Shepmaster Of... of course it was!  Uh... but I'm just going to... change that.  For consistency!  Definitely *not* because I completely screwed it up... *whistles*

Comment: Is it just me or is doing this overly complicated? Is it this difficult in C? Just trying to decide if it is the language that makes this difficult or the lack of a std lib or just how low level the language is. If it is similar in C or C++ then no big deal, if not then why is rust more complicated?

Comment: @electrometro I think it's just you.  The first solution isn't that bad: it has two extra steps on account of Rust needing you to turn the string into an iterator explicitly and convert from `char`s to strings.  The last solution is more or less what you'd do in C.  Depends on how much efficiency you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a performant version, I'd just use this

```
fn digits(mut val: u64) -> Vec<u8> {
    // An unsigned 64-bit number can have 20 digits
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(20);

    loop {
        let digit = val % 10;
        val = val / 10;
        result.push(digit as u8);

        if val == 0 { break }
    }

    result.reverse();
    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", digits(0));
    println!("{:?}", digits(1));
    println!("{:?}", digits(9));
    println!("{:?}", digits(10));
    println!("{:?}", digits(11));
    println!("{:?}", digits(1234567890));
    println!("{:?}", digits(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF));
}
```

This may over allocate by a few bytes, but 20 bytes total is small unless you are doing this a *whole* bunch. It also leaves each value as a number, which you can convert to a string as needed.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
let ss = value.to_string()
              .chars()
              .map(|c| c.to_string())
              .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://is.gd/hIJ1V8)</kbd>

Not the greatest perf but reads well.